# Nested dart project prevents ServiceStack.Razor views from rendering

Tags: c#, dart, servicestack, servicestack-razor

**The situation**

I'm developing a pure ServiceStack/Razor application (no MVC4 or Web API) using licensed ServiceStack 4.0.12.  I have a view (cshtml) that references a Javascript file which is transpiled from a dart project (using AngularDart).

For convenience, I nest the dart project folder within the ServiceStack project, but do not include it in Visual Studio. I then work on my dart project using Dart Editor separately.

The overall project structure looks something like this:

```
MyApp.csproj
Global.asax.cs
\Controllers           <- contains the IService formatted by 'Views\index.cshtml'.
\Dart                  <- not included in Visual Studio project.
     \packages
     \build
           \myapp.dart.js
     \lib
     \web
         \myapp.dart
\Views                 
      \index.cshtml    <- references 'myapp.dart.js'
```

I set up a simple, working ServiceStack/Razor 'Hello World' in Local IIS, then switched to Dart Editor to set up my dart project.

**The problem**

Imagine my frustration switch back a few minutes later only to find that my beautiful 'Hello World' has been replaced by 'Snapshot of Index'.  Without having touched a single line of code, config or re-compiled.

When I switched to IIS Express, the ServiceStack/Razor app would work fine again. Same code, no changes to config or re-compilation.

After losing hair for several hours, poking various config settings and playing with a sandbox project to no effect, I happened to move the 'Dart' folder OUT of the VS project folder, modified Web.config and refreshed the app - and the app worked again!

Sure enough, when I put the 'Dart' folder back into the project folder, modified Web.config and refreshed - the app reverted to Snapshot again.

**The question**

Of course, my question is can anyone tell me why nesting the Dart project folder within the ServiceStack project folder causes ServiceStack.Razor to stop rendering views?

**Edit: More info**

The Dart folder contains the following file types:

- pubspec.yaml
- pubspec.lock
- *.js
- *.dart
- *.json
- a shortcut to the 'packages' folder from the 'web' folder (DartEditor creates this)

**Edit: More info from Mythz's advice**

```
?debug=requestinfo
```

yielded the following StartUpErrors:

```
"StartUpErrors": [
        {
            "ErrorCode": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
            "Message": "Access to the path 'D:\\Semi Da Vinci\\git\\BEAU\\BEAU.Beaufort.git\\Source\\BEAU.Beaufort.Website\\Dart\\packages\\analyzer' is denied.",
            "StackTrace": "[Object: 12/03/2014 4:44:51 PM]:\n[REQUEST: ]\nSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\\Semi Da Vinci\\git\\BEAU\\BEAU.Beaufort.git\\Source\\BEAU.Beaufort.Website\\Dart\\packages\\analyzer' is denied.\r\n   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()\r\n   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualDirectory.GetMatchingFilesInDir(String globPattern)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.Formats.MarkdownFormat.<FindMarkdownPages>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.Formats.MarkdownFormat.RegisterMarkdownPages(String dirPath)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Formats.MarkdownFormat.Register(IAppHost appHost)\r\n   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.LoadPlugin(IPlugin[] plugins)",
            "Errors": []
        },
        {
            "ErrorCode": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
            "Message": "Access to the path 'D:\\Semi Da Vinci\\git\\BEAU\\BEAU.Beaufort.git\\Source\\BEAU.Beaufort.Website\\Dart\\packages\\analyzer' is denied.",
            "StackTrace": "[Object: 12/03/2014 4:44:51 PM]:\n[REQUEST: ]\nSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\\Semi Da Vinci\\git\\BEAU\\BEAU.Beaufort.git\\Source\\BEAU.Beaufort.Website\\Dart\\packages\\analyzer' is denied.\r\n   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()\r\n   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualDirectory.GetMatchingFilesInDir(String globPattern)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.EnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 values, Action`1 action)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorViewManager.Init()\r\n   at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.Init()\r\n   at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.Register(IAppHost appHost)",
            "Errors": []
        },
        {
            "ErrorCode": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
            "Message": "Access to the path 'D:\\Semi Da Vinci\\git\\BEAU\\BEAU.Beaufort.git\\Source\\BEAU.Beaufort.Website\\Dart\\packages\\analyzer' is denied.",
            "StackTrace": "[Object: 12/03/2014 4:44:51 PM]:\n[REQUEST: ]\nSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\\Semi Da Vinci\\git\\BEAU\\BEAU.Beaufort.git\\Source\\BEAU.Beaufort.Website\\Dart\\packages\\analyzer' is denied.\r\n   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()\r\n   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualDirectory.GetMatchingFilesInDir(String globPattern)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.<GetAllMatchingFiles>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at ServiceStack.EnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 values, Action`1 action)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorViewManager.Init()\r\n   at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.Init()\r\n   at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.Register(IAppHost appHost)\r\n   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.LoadPlugin(IPlugin[] plugins)",
            "Errors": []
        }
    ],
```

On closer inspection, the folders underneath /packages are all symlinks to the original libraries in the system cache (more info here: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/faq.html).

Seems like ServiceStack is tripping up on these symlinks.

Comment: Are there any StartupErrors when you go to `?debug=requestinfo` (needs to be in [DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#wiki-debugmode))

Comment: @mythz, thanks for the pointer, I've updated my question with the fallout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with being unable to scan symbolic links in Windows using .NET's File IO API's which are now instead being [logged as warnings in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/88c564f7347cfef52c4179f1e06459d529ed3acb). This fix is available in [MyGet now](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) or in the next **v4.0.13+** on NuGet.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response, as always!